# Android Pixel 2 sending incorrect Content-Type or content

Tags: android, okhttp

We're using okhttp in our project to send a post request to our IoT device.  This code works for every device we have/test **except** for the Google Pixel 2, for some reason it fails every time.

Our firmware developer seems to think what's happening is the phone is saying "I'm sending you content with a length of 1100" but is really only sending 1000 bytes.

It is strange that when the payload is smaller, it seems to work but once it gets to a certain length it stops working, again only on this specific phone.

```
String json = ServiceGenerator.gson.toJson(registerRequest);
byte[] bytes = json.getBytes(Util.UTF_8);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), bytes);

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(PROVISION_HOST + "/v2/prov/registration")
        .post(requestBody)
        .addHeader("Timestamp", timestamp)
        .addHeader("Auth-Hash", authHash)
        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
        Log.e("REGISTRATION RESPONSE", call.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
        Log.e("REGISTRATION RESPONSE", response.body().toString());
        nextStep();
    }
});
```

`registerRequest` is just a JSON string.  According to the request, the `Content-Length` header matches the actual length of `bytes`.

We've tried so many things and are kind of at a loss as to what we can do to fix it.  Is there something we're doing wrong or does this make sense?

Comment: Use something like Charles Proxy or Wireshark to look at the actual request that goes out on the wire; that will help confirm if you're really sending different `Content-Length` values on different phones.

Comment: Ya, I tried that, I'm getting the correct `Content-Length` the only thing I can think of is that maybe the request is getting cut off short somehow?

Comment: Wireshark will show you all of the individual packets sent by your phone -- if they're all making it off the phone, then the problem lies either with the network or with your IoT device. It should be relatively straightforward to rule out the phone, or determine if the Pixel 2 really is behaving differently.

Comment: Yep, I've never used Wireshark before, fascinating.  I can see that the entire message is being sent and it matches the Content-Length. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check does back-end code have limitation. Try to find and fix back-end configs files. In which language written back-end?